# SQL Find the Max value of the sum of two columns

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, max, isnull

This is a two part question ... Firstly I'm stuck on the logic, the second part is a formatting.

The question reads as such: Display all jobs and the maximum total pay (salary + commission) 
for each job. 
The table is called employee -- and the columns that are appropriate here are jobs, salary and commission (both salary and commission have the potential to be null).

```
select * from employee
where sum (SALARY + COMMISSION) =
    (select max (SALARY + COMMISSION)
    From employee)
group by job;
```

I can't for the life of me figure out how to even use ISNULL there too.

You must display the maximum total pay with a dollar ($) sign, a comma, and two decimal places (e.g., $1,234.56). Sort your output by the job.

Do i format it with some command - or can I simply concatenate '$' ... please help.

a few lines for the table:

7839|KING|PRESIDENT||20-NOV-01|5000||50

7596|JOST|VICE PRESIDENT|7839|04-MAY-01|4500||50

7603|CLARK|VICE PRESIDENT|7839|12-JUN-01|4000||50

the create statement:

```
CREATE TABLE employee 
( EMPLOYEE_ID NUMBER(4) PRIMARY KEY,
EMPLOYEE_NAME VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
JOB VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
MANAGER_ID NUMBER(4),
HIRE_DATE DATE,
SALARY NUMBER(9, 2),
COMMISSION NUMBER(9, 2),
DEPARTMENT_ID NUMBER(4) REFERENCES department(DEPARTMENT_ID));
```

Comment: Please provide a sample table and expected output.

Comment: if you need "a dollar ($) sign, a comma, and two decimal places" you can define a scaler value function that do this,but if you want anything else please explain it.

Comment: isnull = coalesce to be more DB Agnostic.

Comment: table create provided, as well as some data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select job, concat('$',format(max(total_pay),2))
from (select job, (coalesce(salary,0) + coalesce(commission,0)) total_pay
    from employee) t1
group by job
order by job
```

Comment: I seem to be getting an error message: Error: near line 8: no such function: concat

Comment: @YelizavetaYR which rdbms are you using?

Comment: I'm using an online compiler -- because i don't have access at the moment to sql server

Comment: @YelizavetaYR try sqlfiddle.com

Comment: @YelizavetaYR are you using mysql or Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: I tried using sqlfiddle it said : Schema Creation Failed: Column, parameter, or variable #1: Cannot specify a column width on data type number.:  (it didn't like int either)

Comment: I modified the code slightly it seemed to not like the format 2 option - and now it works. 

I just did this
    select job, '$' + format(max(total_pay),'.') + '.00'
    from (select job, (coalesce(salary,0) + coalesce(commission,0)) total_pay
        from employee) t1
    group by job
    order by job

Comment: @YelizavetaYR ah ok, i used mysql specific functions because of the mysql tag but it sounds like you're using sql server